# How do threads work in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix

How to reproduce the Output:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int myglobal;

void *thread_function(void *arg) {
  int i,j;
  for ( i=0; i<20; i++ ) {
    j=myglobal;
    j=j+1;
    printf(".");
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
    myglobal=j;
  }
  return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
  pthread_t mythread;
  int i;

  myglobal = 0;

  if ( pthread_create( &mythread, NULL, thread_function, NULL) ) {
    printf("error creating thread.");
    abort();
  }

  for ( i=0; i<20; i++) {
    myglobal=myglobal+1;
    printf("o");
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
  }

  if ( pthread_join ( mythread, NULL ) ) {
    printf("error joining thread.");
    abort();
  }

  printf("\nmyglobal equals %d\n",myglobal);
  exit(0);
}
```

Output:

o..oo..oo..oo..oo..oo..oo..oo..oo..oo..o

myglobal equals21

Question:

Can someone explain how this output is generated?
Why dont they alternate with one another like "o.o.o.o."?

Comment: You should first read what a thread is! There is enough information to be found. Too lazy just reading wikipedia? And why do you expect them to execute alternating?

Comment: The output i expected was: "o.o.o.o" and so on. I dont understand how one thread can overtake the other.

Comment: I dont know if you understand my question. I will try explain again: We have two Threads. One prints "." and pauses for one second. The other prints "o" and also pauses for a second. How is it possible that there are two "oo" and ".." in a row?

Comment: Nobody noticed that there are `sleep` calls to should enforce alternation? That works perfectly alternating on my machine.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès what is the output on your system?

Comment: `o.o.o.o.` (see my answer)

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: Please provide a reference `sleep` is guaranteed to have exact timing.

Comment: No `sleep` has no exact timing, but the drift is negligeable in this case (at least with a such small number of runs); and the execution time of the effective instructions in the loop is far more small than the sleeping time; so an approximation of a perfect timing...

Comment: What sleep does, is that it may or may not generate a context switch. The time it takes for other processes to execute their time slice, you cannot know. So sleep means: "sleep 1 second or longer, or something". Linux (or whatever OS this is) is no RTOS. So there is no guaranteed behavior here. Furthermore, there is possibly a race condition here since both threads write to the same variable. Furthermore, calling stdio functions from several different threads is questionable practice.

Comment: I'm wondering if using a mutex instead of sleep() would change the outcome. I'm not sure how printf() deals with multi-threading.

Comment: @rcgldr, using a mutex or other synchronization object to prevent both threads from running at the same time would be wise, as it is questionable to allow for two threads to simultaneously perform I/O on the same stream.  I'm not quite seeing how just one mutex could be used to ensure alternation of the threads, however.  Personally, I'd probably do it with two semaphores, or with a combination of a flag, a condition variable, and an 
associated mutex.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: `printf()` is thread-safe. The modification of a non-atomic global variable is not.

Comment: @EOF, modification of a non-atomic global variable *under protection of a mutex* is thread safe.  That's part of the basic pattern for use of a condition variable (though it's not essential that the global be non-atomic).

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Sure, I was just pointing out that, yes, you *do* need synchronization, but not for the call to `printf()`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - printf() is thread safe in most environments. My comment was about the effect of using a mutex (or perhaps nothing since printf() is usually thread safe), versus sleep(). I'm wondering if the alternating pairs of output is related to how sleep() is implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each second, your two threads are awaked and try to print their respective char, but you cannot make any assumption about the order they are run again, it seems that in your case you have : `<top>t1 then t2<top>t2 then t1<top>t1 then t2<top>...` which gives you `o..oo..o` etc.

On my system (OSX El Capitan) the scheduling gives me: `o.o.o.o.` etc

On my Solaris, it gives : `o..oo..oo.o.o..oo..oo.o.o..oo.o..oo..oo.`

On my ubuntu : `o.o..o.o.oo..o.oo.o.o.o.o.o.o.o.o.o.o.o.`

Comment: So you say it is a matter of what scheduling my operating system uses? I am using freeBSD as operating system.

Comment: Yes thread scheduling matters of course! I have to make experiments on my different systems.

Answer (score 4):

In your example, there are two threads running simultaneously.  Both started printing at ABOUT the same time, and both are waiting for ABOUT 1 second between printing.  You can't precisely determine the order of the "." vs "o", only that over time, there will be approximately the same number of each.

If, you added a half second sleep:

```
usleep(500000);
for ( i=0; i<20; i++) {
  myglobal=myglobal+1;
  printf("o");
  fflush(stdout);
  sleep(1);
}
```

then the two threads will much more consistently alternate their timing, and you'll get the sequence you expected.  But note that, even then, over long periods of time, the timing of the two threads is not synchronized, and they can drift (and mess up the perfect consistency of "o.o.o.o.o")

Answer (score 3):

> Can someone explain how this output is generated? Why dont they alternate with one another like "o.o.o.o."?

They do not reliably alternate because you provide no mechanism to make them do so.  In particular, your use of the `sleep()` function does not accomplish that objective.  It is not a question of one thread "overtaking" the other.  Rather, at each iteration, both threads become eligible to run at almost exactly the same time, and the machine seems inclined to let the thread that was running last resume first.  That is permitted, but not required.

It is not safe to rely on timing to synchronize thread activities.  You need to use IPC (pipes, signals), or thread synchronization objects such as semaphores, mutexes, or condition variables.

Answer (score 0):

When a thread is created, it inherits its priority from the thread that created it. You also can modify a thread’s priority at any time after its creation by using the setPriority method. At any given time, when multiple threads are ready to be executed, the runtime system chooses for execution the Runnable thread that has the highest priority. Only when that thread stops, yields, or becomes Not Runnable will a lower-priority thread start executing. If two threads of the same priority are waiting for the CPU, the scheduler arbitrarily chooses one of them to run. The chosen thread runs until one of the following conditions is true:

- A higher priority thread becomes runnable.
- It yields, or its run method exits.
- On systems that support time-slicing, its time allotment has expired.

Then the second thread is given a chance to run, and so on, until the interpreter exits.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Very well explained, but unfortunately i cannot refer it to my problem...

Comment: I think it's better for you to learn how threads work than to understand how this program does. look for information about Threads and Scheduling Policies